# How to calculate relative homotopy groups of real projective spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

To calculate homotopy groups of $\pi_n (R P^n, R P^{n-1})$ I first took the LES for the pair and identified $\pi_n (R P^n) = \pi_{n-1} (R P^{n-1})=Z$, $\pi_{n-1} (R P^{n}) = 0$ and what remains of the LES is $\to Z\to\pi_n(RP^n, RP^{n-1})\to Z \to 0$. How do I proceed to get the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence continues one to the left as $\pi_n(\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \pi_n(\mathbb{R}P^n,\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$ for $n>2$. We want to understand the image of this map $\pi_n(\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}) \rightarrow \pi_n(\mathbb{R}P^n)=\mathbb{Z}$. To do this, we may lift this to a map of universal covers, in this case the map lifts to the inclusion of $S^{n-1}$ into $S^n$. This map is nullhomotopic, hence on $\pi_n$, $n>1$, it induces the zero map.

From this we deduce that we have a short exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \pi_n(\mathbb{R}P^n,\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$ since the image of the zero map must be the kernel of $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \pi_n(\mathbb{R}P^n,\mathbb{R}P^{n-1})$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is free, this short exact sequence splits, hence $\pi_n(\mathbb{R}P^n,\mathbb{R}P^{n-1})=\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$, at least if $n>2$. This gives a nice example of the failure of excision for homotopy, since otherwise this group would be $\mathbb{Z}$ since the quotient is homeomorphic to $S^n$.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the splitting of the SES.  Conceivably we can have a SES $0 \to \mathbb{Z\to Z \to Z \to} 0$ where we simply have identities, right?  What exactly forces $\pi_n\left (\mathbb{RP}^n, \mathbb{RP}^{n-1}\right ) = \mathbb{Z\oplus Z}$?

Comment: @Mnifldz That surely is not a SES. You should check that every SES with a free abelian group on the right splits.

Comment: You're right.  That was lazy of me.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Would you care to expand on the last phrase? I was trying to check that $RP^n/RP^{n-1}\cong S^n$ but to no avail

Comment: Isn't $RP^n/RP^{n-1} \cong RP^1 = S^1$, since you're killing $n$ coordinates of $RP^n$?

Comment: @DanielTeixeira This is a topological quotient which collapses the subspace $RP^{n-1}$ to a point. This does not decrease the dimension. To check the stated homemorphism you should use the standard CW decomposition of $RP^n$ which has $RP^{n-1}$ as a (n-1)-skeleton.

Comment: The CW decomposition makes this clear. Thanks!